# How to filter data for one of my variables before proceeding to view data in a table format using R studio

Tags: r, filter, datatable, statistics, conditional-statements

R community! I need some help here.

My question:
I need to create a data table with HER2_IHC and HER2_ISH (my variables). However, I need to filter the data based on a 3rd variable before creating this table. That is, I need to use ONLY data values that are "negative" under HER2_pos (3rd variable).

All of the variables here are categorical.

If you could help me figure out what the right R code is to solve this, it would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: can you provide an example of a negative categorical variable?

Comment: What I meant to say was under the 3rd variable, the results are "negative" or "positive." All of these 3 variables are diagnostic tests, so the results are negative or positive. One of the variables contains "equivocal," so that is why I am using variable 3 to elucidate which of the "equivocal" are really negative or positive.

Comment: It would help to see some example data, in a plain-text format.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

With some guesswork, here's what I make of it.
First we need to create the tibble (data frame) following your suggestions with obviously random data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

data <- tibble(
  VAR1 = sample(c("positive", "negative", "equivocal"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
  VAR2 = sample(c("positive", "negative", "equivocal"), size = 100, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(VAR1 != "equivocal" | VAR2 != "equivocal")

data <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(VAR3 = ifelse(VAR1 == "equivocal" | VAR2 == "equivocal", sample(c("positive", "negative"), size = 1, replace = FALSE), NA))
```

Which gives me this artificial tibble with the required features:

```
> data
# A tibble: 88 x 3
# Rowwise: 
   VAR1      VAR2      VAR3    
   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   
 1 equivocal negative  positive
 2 equivocal negative  positive
 3 positive  equivocal negative
 4 negative  equivocal positive
 5 equivocal negative  positive
 6 positive  negative  NA      
 7 positive  equivocal negative
 8 positive  positive  NA      
 9 positive  positive  NA      
10 positive  positive  NA      
# ... with 78 more rows
```

Under the assumption that this is what you want, the next step is very easy:

```
data <- data %>%
  filter(VAR3 == "negative")
```